# What does the Riesz representation theorem say?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf C}$

I am getting confused by the various different statements of the Riesz representation theorem found on the internet.
So I want to clear up the confusion once and for all.

Let $X$ be a compact metric space.

$\bullet$ $M_s(X)$ denotes the set of all the finite signed Borel measures on $X$.

$\bullet$ $M_c(X)$ denotes the set of all the complex Borel measures on $X$.

$\bullet$ $M(X)$ denotes the set of all the finite (positive) Borel measures on $X$.

$\bullet$ $C(X, \R)$ denotes the space of all the real valued continuous maps on $X$ in the sup-norm topology. This is naturally a real linear space.

$\bullet$ $C(X, \C)$ denotes the space of all the complex values continuous maps in the sup-norm topology. This is naturally a complex linear space.

$\bullet$ $C(X, \R)^*$ denotes the space of all the real valued bounded real-linear maps with domain $C(X, \R)$.

$\bullet$ $C(X, \C)^*$ denotes the set of all the complex valued bounded complex-linear maps with $C(X, \C)$ as the domain.

A member $F\in C(X, \R)^*$ or $C(X, \C)^*$ is said to be **positive** if $F(f)\geq 0$ whenever $f\geq 0$.

> **RRT1.** The map $M_s(X)\to C(X, \R)^*$ defined by $\mu\mapsto (f\mapsto\int_Xf\ d\mu)$ is bijective.
>
> **RRT2.** The map $M(X)\to C(X, \R)^*$ defined by $\mu\mapsto (f\mapsto\int_Xf\ d\mu)$ is injective and has its image as the set of all the positive members of $C(X, \R)^*$.
>
> **RRT3** The map $M_c(X)\to C(X, \C)^*$ defined as $\mu\mapsto (f\mapsto \int_X f\ d\mu)$ is bijective.
>
> **RRT4** The map $M(X)\to C(X, \C)^*$ defined by $\mu\mapsto (f\mapsto\int_X f\ d\mu)$ is injective and has its image as the set of all the positive members of $C(X, \C)^*$.

Which of the above is/are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken all versions should be correct.

One way to proof **RRT1** would be to first show **RRT2** and then apply the Hahn-Jordan-decomposition for a given measure. (see *Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi. Functional Analysis: Introduction to Further Topics in Analysis*, Chapter 1.7)

To verify **RRT3** use **RRT1** on the real and imaginary part of a given measure.

Finally the injectivity of **RRT4** follows from **RRT2**. Let us assume that there is a positive functional $\varphi$, which is not the image of an element $m \in M(X)$. According to **RRT3** we find a complex Borel measure $\mu + i\nu$ ($\mu,\nu \in M_s(X)$) so that $\varphi(f) = \int_Xf\ d(\mu + i\nu$). Assume that $\nu \neq 0$ then we find a Borel set $B$ with $\nu(B) \neq 0$. We can approximate the characteristic function $\chi_{B}$ via continuous positive functions $f_n$ in $L^1$ ($\rightarrow$ mollifiers). Therefore $\nu(B)= Im(\mu + i\nu(B)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} Im(\varphi(f_n) )=0$, since $\varphi$ is positive. Hence $\nu = 0$ and by **RRT2** $\mu$ must be in $M(X)$. Thus **RRT4** is true.